# In Ubuntu, where should I create my eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse

I am just new to Linux and I dont understand the file system as yet. I have to create a new workspace for all my java projects (eclipse workspace). Where should I create the workspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your home directory. Where under there is up to you, but I personally create `~/work/` and then put a subdirectory in there for each class of project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it anywhere you prefer to, but I would recommend it as below:

1. Choose a partition which is formatted with ext3/4 - just because some open source you might work with can include an executable and it gets messy if you're running Windows on same machine and partition is on NTFS.
2. The partition which doesn't host the Linux installation - just in case there is a failure, you don't lose any project you recently worked on, but not checked in to online repository.